# Angular components ngClass

Tags: angular

I have a custom component(my-card) it's row a mat-card material component. How can I bind 
 field with value so, that when I wil use my-card in another component, I will have a possibility to writy my one class and it will be wiht custom styles.

```
    <mat-card [class]="matClass">
  <mat-card-title>{{title}}</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-subtitle>{{subtitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  <mat-card-content>{{content}}</mat-card-content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-card>



import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-card',
  templateUrl: './my-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-card.component.scss']
})
export class MyCardComponent implements OnInit {

@Input()  title: string;
@Input() subtitle: string;
@Input() content: string;
@Input() pathToImg: string;
@Input() matClass: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}


    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'custom';
  content = ['h', 'i', 'g', 'k', 2, 5, 3];
  letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j',  console.log(typeof(this.content))];
  imgUrl = '../code.png';
  class = 'myClass';

  constructor() {}

  onClick() {
    console.log('click');
    // console.log(typeof(this.matClass))
    // console.log(this.matClass)
  }
}

<h1>My custom card</h1>
<app-my-card
[matClass]="class"
[title]="title"
[subtitle]="letters"
><button mat-raised-button (click)="onClick()"> buton</button></app-my-card>



    SCSS ==>    myClass{
      width: 250px;

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvHee.png)

Comment: You have `matClass` input property, you can define a few classes and use the class names dynamically. You're already using it `[matClass]="class"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of changes that you need to do. I would suggest you to go through Angular documentation on [class] and ngClass bindings.

Changes you need to do:

1) Template binding will be as follow:

```
<mat-card [ngClass]="matClass">
  <mat-card-title>{{title}}</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-subtitle>{{subtitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  <mat-card-content [ngClass]="someClass">{{content}}</mat-card-content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-card>
```

2) myCardComponent.ts

```
   @Input() matClass;
   @Input() someClass;
```

3) Set it as true to pass value to mat card component.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'custom';
  content = ['h', 'i', 'g', 'k', 2, 5, 3];
  letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j',  console.log(typeof(this.content))];
  imgUrl = '../code.png';
  class = true;
  displayedClass = {'displayedClassName': false};
  someClass = {'someClassName': false};
  cardio = 'some text';

  constructor() {}

  onClick() {
    console.log('click');
    this.displayedClass = {'displayedClassName': true};
    this.someClass = {'someClassName': true};
  }
}
```

4) In css(style.css), class selector starts with .(dot)

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
.someClassName{
  color: red;
}
.displayedClassName{
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance of your code?

Comment: ty, but it did't help. Maybe I explained some thing wrong. I have a component my-card. It's a row for <mat-card>(angular material), it hase different fields like <mat-content, mat-title, mat-subtitle,> My proble: I need to have possibility to add different classes ass parameter, for example [class]="mat-card", [class2]="mat-title" [class3]="mat-subtitle]. And then, add different styles for this classes.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q4qtld?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: The stackblitz is not even working, can you please provide minimal working code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vn8wg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Please see the working code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zw3c1g    ,,,, I have updated the code as well

Comment: can you plz add me in Discord?;) It's working on stackbiz, but it's not in my prj #5012. v.makhovka

Comment: okey;) TY alot, but, is there an possibility to set styles from local style file, not from -g;

Comment: Hi, yes you can move styles to mycard.component.css by adding a new file. Did it work in your project?

Comment: Do you want to have a call?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I use [matCardClass]="{myClass: true}". And also I add card.scss and import there others scss in my project. It's more comfortable. Thank U for help. U help me very much.

Comment: Hi, maybe u can help me?)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275741/angular-matformcontrol-controlvalueaccessor